# Mailchimp integration with MongoDB + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mailchimp

I currently have a collection of users in a MongoDB database, and I want to send them periodic updates about new content on a real-estate marketplace site daily.

Every day, I would like to email each user information about any new items (if any) that were posted on the marketplace. Is it possible to create such an integration with Mailchimp sending emails based on the MongoDB database programatically, or would another service (or npm library such as nodemailer) be better in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, do this in your application.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one NPM module that looks like it is being kept updated [`mailchimp-api-v3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-v3). Try it out to see if it fits your need.

But because there isn't an official `mailchimp` NPM module, writing your own `mailchimp` client is a valid choice as well. You can use [Mailchimp API](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/) using an HTTP client (like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got))